# MySQL Update column if a value is covered by a range in another table

Tags: mysql

I have 2 simple tables. First table contains the absences made by the workers.

```
tbl_absences
+----+-------------+------------+-----------------------+
| id | id_employee | day_number | is_covered_by_a_range |
+----+-------------+------------+-----------------------+
|  1 |           1 |         18 |       true/false      |
|  2 |           1 |          3 |       true/false      |
|  3 |           2 |         21 |       true/false      |
|  4 |           1 |         13 |       true/false      |
|  5 |           2 |         22 |       true/false      |
|  6 |           1 |         10 |       true/false      |
|  7 |           1 |          7 |       true/false      |
.....
```

The second table contains periods during which the worker was ill and was a medial leave ( days between `range_start` and `range_end` )

```
tbl_sick_leave
+----+-------------+-------------+-----------+
| id | id_employee | range_start | range_end |
+----+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|  1 |           1 |           4 |         8 |
|  2 |           1 |          13 |        18 |
|  3 |           1 |          15 |        21 |
|  4 |           2 |           9 |        12 |
.....
```

I want that column `is_covered_by_a_range` in table `tbl_absences` to hold a boolean value: **true** if that day is covered by any range in `tbl_sick_leave`, and **false** if otherwise.
To update only for worker 1, my approach is a query something like this:

```
update tbl_absences AS a
SET a.is_covered_by_a_range=(EXISTS(
    SELECT * FROM tbl_sick_leave AS s 
    WHERE s.id_employee=1 AND a.day_number BETWEEN s.range_start AND s.range_end
))
WHERE a.id_employee=1
```

Note: `tbl_sick_leave` can hold more than one range that covers a specific day.
Can this be done better? I'm afraid of the performance of such a query when it comes to big tables.

**TEST 1**

```
tbl_absences
+----+-------------+------------+-----------------------+
| id | id_employee | day_number | is_covered_by_a_range |
+----+-------------+------------+-----------------------+
|  1 |           1 |          5 |                    -1 |
|  2 |           1 |         10 |                    -1 |
+----+-------------+------------+-----------------------+

tbl_sick_leave
+----+-------------+-------------+-----------+
| id | id_employee | range_start | range_end |
+----+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|  1 |           1 |           2 |         6 |
+----+-------------+-------------+-----------+
```

Using this  query it will update both rows:

```
update tbl_absences AS a
SET a.is_covered_by_a_range=(EXISTS(
    SELECT * FROM tbl_sick_leave AS s 
    WHERE s.id_employee=1 AND a.day_number BETWEEN s.range_start AND s.range_end
))
WHERE a.id_employee=1
```

result (correct value in `is_covered_by_a_range` ):

```
tbl_absences
+----+-------------+------------+-----------------------+
| id | id_employee | day_number | is_covered_by_a_range |
+----+-------------+------------+-----------------------+
|  1 |           1 |          5 |                     1 |
|  2 |           1 |         10 |                     0 |
+----+-------------+------------+-----------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a `JOIN`

```
UPDATE tbl_absences AS a
LEFT JOIN tbl_sick_leave AS s ON a.id_employee = s.id_employee AND a.day_number BETWEEN s.range_start AND s.range_end
SET a.is_covered_by_a_range = s.id IS NOT NULL
WHERE a.id_employee = 1
```

It's hard to predict the performance, but you should certainly start with indexes on `id_employee` in both tables. If that's not good enough, a composite index on `(id_employee, day_number` in `tbl_absences` might help. If not, post the output of an `EXPLAIN` query.

Comment: An OUTER JOIN in an UPDATE is an unusual thing though

Comment: @Strawberry Quite true, but this is just a variant on the LEFT JOIN - NULL pattern for finding rows with no match.

Comment: I did a test and I updated the question (please see test 1)

Comment: Oh... last condition should be `WHERE a.id_employee = 1` to work. Please correct the answer so I mark as accepted.